# Calendar control selected date WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar

I am trying to bind my `MouseDoubleClick` event to whenever the user double clicks only on a day in the calendar, which will open a new window for that day. However the latter is performed and fetches the highlighted day even if the user double clicks anywhere else in the calendar area.

I tried to do it using the style option however I am getting the same result as if I place it in the calendar definition line:

```
<Calendar x:Name="calendar" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Margin="10,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsTodayHighlighted="True" 
          MouseDoubleClick="event">
```

Same Result as

```
<Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
  <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Cdb_MouseDoubleClick"/>
</Style>
```

How can I differentiate between when a day is press, when the month is pressed, when nothing is pressed, instead of what is focused?

EDIT (this method is working using xaml):

```
<Calendar x:Name="calendar" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Margin="10,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          IsTodayHighlighted="True" SelectionMode="SingleDate">
  <Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
    <Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
      <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="CalendarDayButton_MouseDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>
  </Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
</Calendar>

private void CalendarDayButton_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

Comment: Where did you put your `CalendarDayButton`-Style? I put it into `Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle` and it behaves like you want it

Comment: @nosale Updated in edit

Comment: @nosale I got your point now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, I generally look at `e.OriginalSource`, then walk up the visual tree to find the target parent type, in your case `CalendarDayButton`. The original source is generally a `TextBlock` or some primitive, as that is what user actually clicks on. Also, there is no need for applying a style to `CalendarDayButton`.

So if you put the double click event handler on your `Calendar` as per your first line of code, you can do it like below. There, if a visual parent of the is not found, `FindParentOfType()` method will  return `null`. Then it is just a matter of testing for `null`. If not `null`, means you have the correct target.

```
<Calendar x:Name="calendar" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Margin="10,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsTodayHighlighted="True" 
          MouseDoubleClick="calendar_MouseDoubleClick">


private void calendar_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject originalSource = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
    CalendarDayButton day = FindParentOfType<CalendarDayButton>(originalSource);
    if (day != null)
    {
        //open menu
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}

//and you will need this helper method
//generally a staple in any WPF programmer's arsenal
public static T FindParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject source) where T : DependencyObject
{
    T ret = default(T);
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source);

    if (parent != null)
    {
        ret = parent as T ?? FindParentOfType<T>(parent) as T;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is how I wanted to solve it. The method using style is working fine however I prefer this method as it does not rely on XAML